# how to unregister NFS server from portmap

Tags: nfs

I'm using a proxy server that acts like NFS server. its currently installed on the same machine as the actually nfs server - so I want to change the servers listener setting so I won't clash with the proxy NFS server.

so I've changed the port my NFS server listens on to 2050 ( default was  2049 ) at `/etc/nfsmount.conf`.

now I would like to **unregister** the NFS server from the **Portmap**.

the portmap manual has nothing about this and I couldn't find a configuration file for it.

Comment: `man rpcinfo` , it can unregister stuff from portmap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to @nos I've found that I can use `rpcinfo -d PROG_NUMBER VERSION` to unregister a program from the portmap